# Calling a java function with parameter within javascript function

Tags: java, javascript, forms, validation, parameters

is it possible to call java method within a javascript function? Let me explain my problem:

I am working with JSP (have to) and I have a JavaScript form validator which is checking whether a entered value is allowed. It depends on whether there already is such an entry in my MySQL DB. The Script looks like the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <% DbConnection db = new DbConnection(); %>
    function validateForm()
        {
            var x=document.forms["form"]["name"].value;
            if (<%= db.validateName("%> x <%=") %>)
                {
                    alert("Themenname bereits vergeben.");
                    return false;
                }
        }
</script>
```

So what I have to do is passing the entered value (javascript parameter) to my java method (db.validateName) in order to receive a boolean value.

Any idea how to solve this? Java runs server-side whereas JS runs on the client-side, right? Unfortunately I have no clue on how else I could validate from mySQL db.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Send an AJAX request, check the value at server-side, and send the result in the response.

Comment: Yes it is valid, you are using jsp scriptlets which interns converts into java code. But scriptlets are not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You need send to the server your validation, with AJAX, you can use a Servlet or another JSP validation that receives the validation input and response with validation result/message to the client.

render your html -> fire the event to validate -> send to the servlet/jsp in to server side -> validate into server -> response to the cliente -> in the client receive the server response -> in the client side render the validation menssage -> process form

Answer (score 0):

You have to use AJAX.

You can have a look at DWR also if you want, here is the link http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html